# How to call PDF on a network folder for showing it in iframe generated with php

Tags: php, file, networking, iframe, directory

it's not that complicated as it may sound in title, but here is my code:

```
<?php
echo '<iframe src="\\servername\pdf\test.pdf"></iframe>';
?>
```

My error in this case is, that file cannot be found on this server. So I have local network nad I would like to call pdf file on other server. PHP keeps trying to tell me that file doesn't exists on this server. How to switch to another server?

Thank you guys,
best!

Comment: try: `<iframe src="file://servername/pdf/test.pdf"></iframe>`

Comment: i tried that one - it's better - now if i click on link in source code it opens, but it doesn't load in browser - console says "Not allowed to load local resource"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote your path , represents location of current or local storage device. To indicate some remote location you need to specify path along with protocol like 'http://' .
For example
'http://location.com/name.pdf'
('http://' - if site is using http protocol)

Comment: hello, i tried that one too - now it's taking longer to load, but it fails - browser says "time limit expired" and console says error in GET (path)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but this worked for me :

```
<iframe src="file://///SERVERNAME/FOLDER/"></iframe>
```

Yes it is 5 forward slashes